# SQL Server How to construct subqueries to JOIN Field Descriptions to IDs

Tags: sql-server, join, subquery

I am trying to return results that replace record Ids with their more human readable description values. Changing the column names via AS is simple enough but I think a subquery is going to be needed to take an ID values such as PT1 and get the Description value as a replacement.

For instance I have a table1 with some columns like:

### id| Paper | Coating | CreatedOn | Type

1 | pid3 | cid5 | some date | tid2
2 | pid2 | cid8 | some date | tid3
3 | pid1 | cid1 | some date | tid4

Then table2 has details on the reference id in the parent table:

### id| fKey | description |

1 | pid3 | some user friendly description | 
1 | pid1 | some other description         | 
1 | pid2 | something else                 |

Similar for tables three and four

I tried to use a JOIN linking the Paper IDs but this returned no values

SELECT table1.Paper as 'Paper Name', table1.Coating, table1.CreatedOn, table1.Type, table2.description
FROM table1
JOIN table2 ON table1.Paper = table2.fKey

My actual query is as shown but the table names were altered:

```
SELECT PD_ComboRun.RNId AS 'RUN #', PD_ComboRun.RNQty AS Quantity,
       PD_ComboRun.PTId, PD_ComboRun.PSId AS Size, PD_ComboRun.RNType AS 'Run Type',
       PD_ComboRun.PCId AS 'Press Coating', PD_ComboRun.UVFid AS 'UV Finish',
       PD_ComboRun.Notes AS 'Special Instructions', PD_ComboRun.CreatedOn AS 'Date Created', 
       SM_PaperType.PTCode AS Paper, SM_PaperType.PTId AS Expr1
FROM  PD_ComboRun 
LEFT JOIN SM_PaperType ON SM_PaperType.PTId = PD_ComboRun.PTId
```

Can someone please point me the right direction to achieve this goal?  Thanks!

Comment: You may want to reconsider having a separate id column in table2.  From your description, it appears that fKey really is the id.  A good test is, will that value EVER be repeated in Table2.  If not, it should be the primary key of that table since table2 contains the details of the paper and table1 simply links to it by the paper id.

Comment: I've updated the actual query to show real values.
The Join, which I expected to work returns no values but the logic of using that parent table PD_ComboRun and it paper type column of PTId should be able to then pull from the sibling table SM_PaperType the PTCode value by linking the SM_PaperType.PTId = PD_ComboRun.PTId

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works perfectly as I presume you need.  I modified it to use your tables and fields.

```
DECLARE @PD_ComboRun TABLE(RNId int,RNQty int,PTId varchar(10),
    PSId varchar(10),PCId varchar(10),UVFid varchar(10),createdOn smalldatetime, 
    RNType varchar(10),Notes varchar(MAX))
INSERT INTO @PD_ComboRun
SELECT 1,5,'pid3','psid1','cid5','uvid1',GETDATE(),'tid2',''
UNION ALL
SELECT 2,10,'pid2','psid2','cid8','uvid4',GETDATE(),'tid3','notes'
UNION ALL
SELECT 3,7,'pid1','psid1','cid1','uvid1',GETDATE(),'tid4',''

SELECT * FROM @PD_ComboRun

DECLARE @SM_PaperType TABLE(PTId varchar(10),PTCode varchar(50))
INSERT INTO @SM_PaperType
SELECT 'pid3','some user friendly description'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'pid2','some other description'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'pid1','something else'

SELECT * FROM @SM_PaperType

SELECT t1.RNId AS [Run #], t1.RNQty AS Quantity,
    t1.PTId,t1.PSId AS Size,t1.RNType AS [Run Type], 
    t1.PCId AS [Press Coating], t1.UVFid AS 'UV Finish', 
    t1.Notes AS 'Special Instructions',t1.createdOn AS 'Date Created',
    t2.PTCode AS Paper,t2.PTId AS Expr1
FROM @PD_ComboRun t1 INNER JOIN @SM_PaperType t2 ON t1.PTId=t2.PTId
```

RESULTS

@table1

```
1   5   pid3    psid1   cid5    uvid1   2012-05-31 17:45:00 tid2    
2   10  pid2    psid2   cid8    uvid4   2012-05-31 17:45:00 tid3    notes
3   7   pid1    psid1   cid1    uvid1   2012-05-31 17:45:00 tid4
```

@table2

```
pid3    some user friendly description
pid2    some other description
pid1    something else
```

@combined
[image]

Comment: This really helped. Turns out the DB actually was bound to another field value rather than what was the expected fKey. Problem sorted! Thanks to ALL that contributed!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
FROM  Table1 LEFT JOIN Table2 ON Table2.PTId = Table1.PCId
```

This looks like the smoking gun, shouldn't it be Table1.PTId? Given the sample data in Table2 only showed values for PTId that is. Perhaps you're creating a general purpose table, however if that is the case, the "FK" in Table2 should be renamed so it doesn't collide with Table1.